# Determine what subparser is used

Tags: python, argparse

I'm building a software which has several subparsers, I'd like those ones having a different `convert_arg_line_to_args` definition so what I did is to replace the function of my parser considering the subparser selected:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Available sub commands')

sub_parser = subparsers.add_parser("sub1", help="sub1")
sub_parser.add_argument("--paramsub1", required=True, dest="paramsub1")
sub_parser.set_defaults(cmd_object="sub1")

sub_parser = subparsers.add_parser("sub2", help="sub2")
sub_parser.add_argument("--paramsub2", required=True, dest="paramsub2")
sub_parser.set_defaults(cmd_object="sub2")
```

I'd like argparse do not check the arguments, but tell me which subparser has been selected:

```
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
if args["cmd_object"] == "sub1": parser.convert_arg_line_to_args = function1
elif args["cmd_object"] == "sub2": parser.convert_arg_line_to_args = function2
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to check the subparser name just so you can set the `convert_arg_line_to_args` function?  You could, instead, change that function during setup.

How about this setup?

```
def function1(arg_line):
    print('function1: %r'%arg_line)
    return [arg_line]

def function2(arg_line):
    print('function2: %r'%arg_line)
    return arg_line.split()

parser = ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Available sub commands', dest='cmd_object')

sub_parser1 = subparsers.add_parser("sub1", help="sub1",fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
sub_parser1.convert_arg_line_to_args = function1
sub_parser1.add_argument("--paramsub1")

sub_parser2 = subparsers.add_parser("sub2", help="sub2",fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
sub_parser2.convert_arg_line_to_args = function2
sub_parser2.add_argument("--paramsub2")
```

I moved `fromfile_prefix_chars='@'` from the parser to the subparsers.  That way the parser does not try to read the argument files.

Usually required arguments are defined as `positional` (without the `--`).

Using `dest='cmd_object'` puts the subparser name into the namespace.  `sest_defaults` also works, but is more useful when you want to set that value to a function (or other non-string).